# Help with configuring CiviCRM

Tags: contacts, contributions

new to Civi CRM and really need help with setting up / customising. Anyone here that does that as volunteer for charity or paid ? looked on peopleperhour and cannot find

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackExchange.  You can find many people who will do this on a paid basis at https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

If you want to do it yourself and have specific questions then ask away on this site.

If you describe what your charity is, it may just resonate with someone willing to offer more substantial pro-bono help - but that's an exception.

Comment: Thanks, we are a charity based in London helping homeless teenagers with accommodation, training and employment